# How to create the same schema in Mysql, which is present in H2 db connected with activiti enterprise bpm

Tags: activiti

I have one issue regarding creation of schema in MySql.
I am using Activiti bpm enterprise edition for designing my process flow which is now connected to the default H2 database.
Now, I want it to get connected to MySQL which I have done by changing the driver, url , username , password in activiti-app.properties file.

But in order to save my data model or process diagram i want the same schema structure present in H2 database in Mysql in order to save my process diagram in MySQL.

Does activiti provides any way to copy the schema structure from one database to other.

I have tried using Squirrel client, Razon SQl but nothing helped as such.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the schema is automatically copied into your database, that is what happened for me. Check the database, using

> Show tables;

from your command prompt once you're connected to the database you created. This should show you the same tables with the same schema as used in the default H2 database.